# MySQL join not returning the rows when trying to count from left table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have 2 tables, articles and article_comments. Trying to get the comment count on the article listing page. However, any articles which do not have any comment under it is not being returned by my query.

```
SELECT `articles`.*, COUNT(comments.id) AS comment_count 
FROM `articles` as `articles` 
LEFT JOIN `article_comments` as `comments` ON `articles`.`id` = `comments`.`article_id`
```

How can I make the query return all rows from articles with **comment_count** as **0** if there are no comments for that post?

Comment: As written that query should do what you want (although it will give `NULL` as `comment_count` for any article with no comments; you can convert that to `0` with `COALESCE`). Is there a `WHERE` clause you're not showing us?

Comment: I do NOT see GROUP BY clause in your query. You must use window variant of a function: ```SELECT `articles`.*, COUNT(comments.id) OVER () AS comment_count ...```

Comment: @Nick There is no where clause. Problem is it is not returning the articles which do not have comment.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. But--This is a faq. (Obvously.) Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your query is missing a `GROUP BY` clause, that should enumerate all the columns from the `articles` table - or, if you are running MySQL with sql mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` disabled, it shoul contain the primary key of `articles`.

It might be simpler to express this with a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    a.*,
    coalesce(
        (select count(*) from article_comments ac where ac.article_id = a.id),
        0
    ) comments_count
from articles a
```

You can also pre-aggregate in a subquery:

```
select
    a.*,
    coalesce(c.comments_count, 0) comments_count
from articles a
left join (
    select article_id, count(*) comments_count
    from article_comments
    group by article_id
) c on c.article_id = a.id
```